# Mongoid associations, lazy loading, and all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, associations, mongoid

I have the following model

```
class Vote
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :value, :type => Symbol # can be :aye, :nay, :abstain, :present

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :polco_group
  belongs_to :bill
```

and Bill

```
class Bill

has_many :votes
```

and a User

```
class User
  has_many :votes
```

I am trying to implement the following test

```
    b = Bill.new
    @user1.vote_on(b, :aye)
    assert_equal :aye, b.voted_on?(@user1)
```

This test is failing, because if I follow those steps, `b.votes.all` is empty, but `b.votes` has the data we need. However, if I open the rails console, I get that `b.votes` is [], but `b.votes.all` is fully populated if I follow these steps. I am sure there is something simple I'm missing here. When is b.votes [] and the .all needed?

my methods:

```
# in User.rb

def vote_on(bill, value)
    # test to make sure the user is a member of a group
    my_groups = self.joined_groups
    unless my_groups.empty?
      unless bill.voted_on?(self)
        my_groups.each do |g|
          unless Vote.create(:value => value, :user => self, :polco_group => g, :bill => bill)
             raise "vote not valid"
          end
        end
      end
      #bill.save!
    else
      raise "no joined_groups for this user"
    end
  end
```

and

```
# in Bill.rb
 def voted_on?(user)
    if votes = self.votes.all.select{|v| v.user == user}
      votes.map{|v| v.value}.first
    else
      nil
    end
  end
```

Comment: Try replacing `Bill.new` with `Bill.create`, probably that should solve most of your problems. If it works let me know, will try to explain the logic.

Comment: I even use an existing bill loaded by Fabrications and I still have this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a result of issue #1198. Try reloading your object after setting the relation.

https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/1198

Comment: You're welcome, mate. And apologies for the bug. If you keep an eye on that GitHub issue, you'll be notified of updates.